# Modified USB Keyboard Driver Not Receiving Key Presses (Linux)

Tags: linux-kernel, keyboard, usb, linux-device-driver, irq

I am trying to write a modified/custom USB keyboard driver.  I'm having an issue with the irq handler not receiving key presses as expect.

What I've done:

1. Made a copy of `/linux/driver/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c` [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c) and modified `usb_kbd_id_table` to have only the vendor id and product id associated with my keyboard.
2. Built the modified driver.
3. Inserted the modified driver with `sudo insmod usbkbd.ko`.
4. Prevented the keyboard from being associated with the standard HID driver by adding `usbhid:quirks=0x03eb:0x20ff:0x4` to `/etc/default/grub`.

Behavior:

1. Upon plugging in the keyboard, it is correctly associated with my driver.  I know this because I see a `printk` statement that I added in `usb_kbd_probe` show up in `/var/log/syslog`.  It actually shows up twice because the device has 2 interfaces.
2. The function `usb_kbd_irq` is repeatedly called in a loop.  I have added a `printk` here as well and I see that `kbd->new` always has `0` in every byte.
3. This loop continues rapidly and pressing any of the keys has no effect (`kbd->new` always has `0` in every byte regardless of keys pressed).

I have tried using wireshark to view the usb trafic and I see that the host and device are going back and forth.  I was expecting one way traffic.
[wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtH8o.png)

I am confused about why the key presses have no effect.  Shouldn't I see some data in `kbd->new` if a key has been pressed?

Edit: Screen shot with device info at `https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNq4e.png`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the way I was dissociating the device with the generic USBHID driver.  Listed in set 4 above:

4. Prevented the keyboard from being associated with the standard HID driver by adding usbhid:quirks=0x03eb:0x20ff:0x4 to /etc/default/grub

If I instead unbind the device manually and bind it to my driver then the IRQ no longer loops and I do in fact see different input for each key press.  I used instructions found here https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/